# put tables side by side with divs

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to learn spanish and basic webdesign at the same time. I am trying to organize these tables side by side but they are not aligning next to each other. I thought all you needed to do was to put in float: left in the css classes however it is not working. Please help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .vertfirst {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.first {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    background-color:blue;
}

.second {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    background-color:blue;
}
.third {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    background-color:blue;
}
    </style>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div class="vertfirst">
        <div class="first">
        <table>
        1-9
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>unidades</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>uno</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>dos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>tres</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>cuatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>cino</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>sies</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>siete</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>ocho</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>nueve</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
        </br>
<!--10-90-->
        <div class="second">
        <table>
        10-90
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>decenas</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>diez</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>veinte</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>treinta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>cuarenta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>cincuenta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>sesenta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>70</td>
        <td>setenta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>ochenta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>90</td>
        <td>noventa</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
        </br>
<!--100-900-->
        <div class="third">
        <table>
        100-900
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>centenas</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>cien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>doscientos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>300</td>
        <td>trescientos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>cuatrocientos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>quinientos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>600</td>
        <td>siescientos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>700</td>
        <td>setecientos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>800</td>
        <td>ochocientos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>900</td>
        <td>novecientos</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close your `div`s with `<div>`. It should be `</div>`.

You also need to remove your `</br>`s (which by the way, don't exist, a line break is `<br/>`).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m233m/

Comment: `<br/>` is only used if you have an `XHTML` doctype, otherwise you should use `<br>` without the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing your tables within 2 table td's... like so

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="50%" valign="top">

//Place Your First Tables Code Here

</td>
<td width="50%" valign="top">

//Place Your Second Tables Code Here

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```